# Connect to node js server running on vagrant machine

Tags: node.js, vagrant, localhost, virtualbox, portforwarding

I have a simple `node http server` running on a `vagrant` VM. I would like to address to it with my browser on my local machine.

```
varhttp=require("http");

http.createServer(function(request,response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "config.sh"
end
```

I can't figure out how to address it from my browser.

Whenever I do `curl localhost:3000` in the vagrant VM, I get the `Hello world` message.

From my local machine I get `This site can’t be reached` whenever I try to open `localhost:8080`, as suggested in [Vagrant forwarding](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html).

Comment: You've literally copied the forwarding line without understanding what it does? You need to forward 3000

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, I was asking for some clarification, thanks!. Now I understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your forward config forwards 80, but your application listens on 3000.  Fix that and it should work.

Answer (score 6):

`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 8080`

Comment: For complete Vagrant noobs like myself, this configuration is found in the `Vagrantfile`.