# Cannot connect to node js server hosted on vagrant machine

Tags: node.js, vagrant

I'm trying out vagrant as a local testing server and I'm having difficulty connecting to nodejs app server from the hosting windows machine, but I can connect to nginx server just fine.

My vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.55"
  end

  config.vm.define "app_0" do |app_0|
    app_0.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    app_0.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.1"
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "55.55.55.56"
  end
end
```

My node js index.js(helloworld) from app_0 at 55.55.55.1:

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

// Listen on port 80, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(80, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log('Listening to port:  ' + 80);
});
```

Which is run with sudo node index.js and is visible locally on the vagrant machine, but I cannot connect to it from hosting machine at 55.55.55.1:80

Please do not mark this duplicate of this: [Connect to node js server running on vagrant machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389776/connect-to-node-js-server-running-on-vagrant-machine) as it does not use port-forwarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 things:

- `55.55.55.x` is not a private network IP (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) so you might reach a valid IP and even when setting your host file, you might have conflict.
- Do not use address with `.1` at the end, it is the default gateway/router
  so how vagrant will reach the host.

Pick a valid IP from the private network range and it will work

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define "web" do |web|
    web.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    web.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.55.10"
  end

  config.vm.define "app_0" do |app_0|
    app_0.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    app_0.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.55.11"
  end

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    db.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.55.12"
  end
end
```

Comment: Huh, one thing I don't get is that 55.55.55.1 still didn't work after I disconnected from my network. I tried 10.0.0.10 and worked like a charm. Thanks!